# C++ : Why is move constructor not getting called?

Tags: c++, move-constructor

I am experimenting with the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    int data;
public:
   A(): data{0}
   {

   }

   A(const A& other)
   {
       print(other);
   }


   A(A&& other)
   {
       print(other);
   }

   void print(const A& other) const
   {
      cout << "In print 1" << endl;
   }

   void print(const A&& other) const
   {
      cout << "In print 2" << endl;
   }

};


int main() {
    A a0;
    A a1(a0);
    A a2(A());

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting the output to be :

```
In print 1
In print 1
```

However, the [actual output](https://ideone.com/qpDoaG) is :

```
In print 1
```

Clearly, the move constructor is not getting called. Why so? And what is getting called in its place during construction of `a2`?

Comment: A a3(std::move(a0))

Comment: If you are in C++17 then you won't observe move- (or copy-) construction in `A a2(A{});` or `A a2 = A();` - all of these will just initialize `a2` using `A`'s default constructor. No temporary is created, copied, moved or assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `A a2(A());` is actually function declaration, not a declaration of an object. See this:

[My attempt at value initialization is interpreted as a function declaration, and why doesn't A a(()); solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/my-attempt-at-value-initialization-is-interpreted-as-a-function-declaration-and)

If you want to see the move constructor, do something like this:

```
A a2((std::move(A())));
```

Comment: Or `A a2(A{});` (if move constructor is not elided).

Comment: Note that neither `A a2 = A();` nor `A a2(A{});` (nor something like `A a2 = A(A(A()));` call the move constructor in C++17. The temporary is never materialized. See https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.init#17.6.1.